# Jacoco with POM Packing

Tags: java, code-coverage, pom.xml, jacoco

Hi I am new to pom's and jacoco.  I am trying to get code coverage binaries to get generated.  I run mvn install but I do not see anything getting generated.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I followed several tutorials where you define the plugin, setup the prepare-agent and report goals, and set a property name to used in the surefire and failsafe plugin.  Not exactly sure why on the last one.

Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxxx-xxxxx</artifactId>
    <version>2018.17.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>xxxxx xxxxx Integration Project</name>

    <modules>
        <!-- module>devenv-setup</module -->
        <module>libraries</module>
        <module>brokers</module>
        <module>liquibase</module>
        <module>testing</module>
        <module>packer</module>
    </modules>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:https://bitbucket.org/xxxxxwholesale/xxxxx-xxxxx.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://bitbucket.org/xxxxxwholesale/xxxxx-xxxxx</url>
    </scm>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-aws</id>
            <name>nexus-release</name>
            <url>http://nexus.devops.inetwork.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>nexus-aws</id>
            <name>nexus-snapshot</name>
            <url>http://nexus.devops.inetwork.com/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <project.rootDir>${project.basedir}/</project.rootDir>
        <build_timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</build_timestamp>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>

        <!-- test running enabled by default -->
        <!-- override by passing cmd line args -->
        <!-- below props are set to ${skipTests} to be backward compatible with -DskipTests -->
        <!-- to skip unit tests: -Dut.skip -->
        <ut.skip>${skipTests}</ut.skip>
        <!-- to skip integration tests: -Dit.skip -->
        <it.skip>${skipTests}</it.skip>

        <assertj.version>3.8.0</assertj.version>
        <commons-csv.version>1.5</commons-csv.version>
        <commons-compress.version>1.5</commons-compress.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.6</commons-io.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.6</commons-lang3.version>
        <feign-form.version>3.0.3</feign-form.version>
        <guava.version>23.5-jre</guava.version>
        <httpcomponents.version>4.5.3</httpcomponents.version>
        <ignite.version>2.3.0</ignite.version>
        <janino.version>3.0.8</janino.version>
        <kafka.version>0.10.1.1</kafka.version>
        <libphonenumber.version>8.8.8</libphonenumber.version>
        <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.20.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <metrics-spring.version>3.1.3</metrics-spring.version>
        <mockserver-netty.version>5.3.0</mockserver-netty.version>
        <okhttp.version>2.7.5</okhttp.version>
        <spring-boot.version>1.5.9.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring-data.version>Kay-SR2</spring-data.version>
        <spring-kafka.version>1.1.7.RELEASE</spring-kafka.version>
        <springfox.version>2.7.0</springfox.version>
        <zohhak.version>1.1.1</zohhak.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-aws</id>
            <name>nexus-public</name>
            <url>https://nexus.devops.inetwork.com/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-data.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>xxxxx-common</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>provisioning-objects</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>provisioning-util</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>orphan-objects</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>tools-objects</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>crm-objects</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>billing-objects</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>whitelist-objects</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>datarecords-objects</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>dth-objects</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>testing</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx.testing</groupId>
                <artifactId>functional</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx.testing.functional</groupId>
                <artifactId>common</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>test-jar</type>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx.functional</groupId>
                <artifactId>provisioningbillingpipeline</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx.testing.functional</groupId>
                <artifactId>orphanqueuepipeline</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>brokers</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx.brokers</groupId>
                <artifactId>provisioning</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx.brokers</groupId>
                <artifactId>billing</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx.brokers</groupId>
                <artifactId>crm</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>tract-client</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>roger-client</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>dth-client</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx.brokers</groupId>
                <artifactId>datarecords</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>immutable</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxxxx</groupId>
                <artifactId>xxxxx-common-testing</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.ryantenney.metrics</groupId>
                <artifactId>metrics-spring</artifactId>
                <version>${metrics-spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-csv.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-compress.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>${guava.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
                <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
                <version>${okhttp.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
                <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
                <version>${okhttp.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>${springfox.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>${springfox.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Conditional logging -->
            <!-- https://logback.qos.ch/setup.html#janino -->
            <!-- https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#conditional -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
                <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
                <version>${janino.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Google phone number validation for E164 DID validation and simple manipulation -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
                <version>${libphonenumber.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>${httpcomponents.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
                <version>${httpcomponents.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
                <version>${httpcomponents.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
                <artifactId>feign-httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>9.5.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.github.openfeign.form</groupId>
                <artifactId>feign-form-spring</artifactId>
                <version>${feign-form.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.netflix.feign</groupId>
                <artifactId>feign-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>8.18.0</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.netflix.feign</groupId>
                        <artifactId>feign-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
                <version>${kafka.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>${kafka.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <!-- These must be excluded because they are included elsewhere and the multiple inclusion
                    will result in a weird condition that generates a null pointer  -->
                    <!--
                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError.
                    See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
                    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.<clinit>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:49)
                    -->
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-kafka.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
                <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
                <version>${ignite.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
                <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
                <version>${ignite.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
                <artifactId>ignite-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>${ignite.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
                <artifactId>ignite-spring-data</artifactId>
                <version>${ignite.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
                <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
                <version>${assertj.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                        <compilerArgs>
                            <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                            <!-- disable warning on "No processor claimed any of these annotations" -->
                            <arg>-Xlint:-processing</arg>
                        </compilerArgs>
                        <!-- Prevents an endPosTable exception during compilation -->
                        <!-- This is required for org.immutables to generate the Immutable classes -->
                        <!-- Check https://immutables.github.io/getstarted.html#troubleshooting -->
                        <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <forkMode>never</forkMode>
                        <skipTests>${ut.skip}</skipTests>
                        <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/Test_*.java</include>
                            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/IT_*.java</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/FT_*.java</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/Manual_*.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <testInfo.version>${project.version}</testInfo.version>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <!-- https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp -->
                        <!--<argLine>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom</argLine>-->
                        <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                        <!-- -->
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <forkMode>never</forkMode>
                        <skipTests>${it.skip}</skipTests>
                        <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/IT_*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <!-- https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp -->
                        <!--<argLine>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom</argLine>-->
                        <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputEncoding>${project.encoding}</outputEncoding>
                        <sourceEncoding>${project.encoding}</sourceEncoding>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which
                          is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed. -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                                <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo
                                  runtime agent. -->
                                <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created
                          after unit tests have been run. -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>post-unit-test</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                                <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                                <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo
                                  runtime agent. -->
                                <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>post-integration-test</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                                <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Ensures that poms are formatted/layed out according to maven conventions -->
            <!-- Will fail the build if violations are found -->
            <!-- To fix run: mvn tidy:pom -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/developers/conventions/code.html#POM_Code_Convention -->
            <!-- http://www.mojohaus.org/tidy-maven-plugin/ -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tidy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```